# LibGDX - can't run destop version from Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, desktop

I have followed video fpr LibGDX https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXO0aT6rXTQ
but can't run desktop version from Android Studio

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=E:\Android\Android-Studio\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;E:\Coding\MyGdxGame\desktop\build\classes\main;E:\Coding\MyGdxGame\core\build\classes\main;E:\Android\Android-Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain io.github.paulvi.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 3 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always download the IntelliJ community version, which works better with the project setup LibGDX generates: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

In any case, have you tried: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA#running-your-project